# CKEditor shrinks in Firefox when created on element with empty text

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

When I start CKEditor inline (like this: `ckeditor = CKEDITOR.inline(element);` ) on element with no text in Firefox, whole editable line is shrinked to few pixels. When I type something, CKEditor is resized to normal height.

When I start editing some text and then manually delete it, height stays normal. I want to do the same in the code. So I add some default text to those empty lines and then delete it when CKEditor starts editing that element. I tried `ckeditor.setData("");` after starting CKEditor, but it still shrinks in Firefox.

Comment: Perhaps you should set `line-height` in CSS for that element?

Comment: This doesn't work when line is empty. Maybe edit some CSS of CKEditor would helps, but I can't find the right one. (I wanted to change border color of CKEditor before, because in Chrome it has blue border and in FF is no border, but I didn't find where it is set.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by added this to my CSS:

```
.element-class {
    min-height: 1.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `CKEDITOR.replace('selector');`
And place selector into relative positioning box

Comment: It's not what I need. This creates whole text area instead of just making line editable.